# Objective-C NSMutableArray alloc init on already declared Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have been tasked with "cleaning up" someone else's Objective-C code.  I will admit, it is certainly not my favorite language.

One method i found in this user's code that seems redundant to me is this:

```
if (favoriteItemsArray || [favoriteItemsArray count] > 0) {
    [favoriteItemsArray removeAllObjects];
    favoriteItemsArray = nil;
}

if (favoriteOrderArray || [favoriteOrderArray count] > 0) {
    [favoriteOrderArray removeAllObjects];
    favoriteOrderArray = nil;
}

favoriteItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
favoriteOrderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I wanted to double check with you all and see if i am just too use to JAVA, but couldn't this code be condensed to just the last two lines and just merely say:

```
favoriteItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
favoriteOrderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If not can someone explain?

Again this is not my code..

Comment: I am trying to think of some vague situation of retention that requires removing the objects before reinitializing, but I can't come up with one.  I'd say go ahead with your approach.

Comment: Those two `if` statements are bad. The `||` part is pointless.

Comment: Are the last two lines inside or outside the 1st `if` statement? You don't show the closing curly brace.

Comment: the || is pointless as well, I agree.. the two init/alloc statements are out side both if conditions

Comment: @rmaddy All braces are there

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Yeah, I see that now. I let the bad indenting confuse me. :)

Comment: sorry it auto indented like that.. my bad for not correcting it.. I want to throw all this guys code out, as if Objective-C isn't hard enough to read, this guy is over conditioning everywhere and all his ViewControllers are riddled with redundant code

Comment: @erik I think that piece of code is still there because the project was probably ported from non-ARC to ARC.

Comment: Even prior to ARC the code was bogus (and even when the bogus `||` is ignored).  Whoever wrote it was not very well educated on how Objective-C works.

Comment: And if the guy did that he probably does `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@":someString]` in several places.

Comment: in fact he does do that, what is that @"%@"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. You can remove the first part of the code (if ARC is used for reference counting). When the arrays are reassigned, the previous array will be freed because the retain count will reach zero and all objects in the array will also be released.

Comment: i will accept this answer in a few minutes (StackOverFlow won't let me yet..  that was an easy reputation booster!